# Incompatible types error in android studio with osmdroid

Tags: java, android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using `osmdroid` maps in my project.

I just created a sample project but I'm getting the following error

> Required: org.osmdroid.view.MapController
>
> Found:    org.osmdroid.api.IMapController

I just copied entire example from osmdroid documentation even though it shows me error.

My `OsmDroidTest` class is as follows,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class OsmDroidTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private MapController mapController;
    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();    //error is at this line
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134733);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);
    }
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: mapView.getController() seems to be returning IMapController which the MapController implements. Changing private MapController mapController to IMapController mapController should make it work.

Comment: @dnivra I changed it, and it works now! Could you say the difference between `MapController` and `IMapController`? I took the above code from one simple example there it was written `MapController`